# Deploy nodeJS app in production mode in Dokku

Tags: node.js, angular, dokku

When I deploy a nodeJS app to Dokku via Git, it runs the command:

```
-----> Build
   Running build

   > my-project-name@0.0.0 build /tmp/build
   > ng build
```

This is an Angular app and I'd like it to build in production mode, ie: `ng build --aot --prod`.

How can I affect the command that is run during Dokku's build phase?

Here's the `scripts` part of my `package.json`:

```
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
```

I've tried adding `"postinstall": "ng build --aot --prod"` to the above. That does indeed run the right command just after installation, but then the build phase kicks in and it runs `ng build` all over again (so overriding the production).

Perhaps I could change `"build": "ng build"` above to add `--aot --prod` - but I'm not sure what effect that would have when running my Node app locally, where I never want `--prod`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the `ng build --aot --prod` in your local machine, then commit the dist folder (remove it from .gitignore).
Then just create an empty file called exactly ".static" on the root folder of the project.

Then on the dokku server run:

dokku config:set yourappname NGINX_ROOT=dist BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/dokku/buildpack-nginx

Then run "git push dokku master".

With that approach you won't have to worry about the package.json scripts.

Comment: Interesting approach! Thanks for that, I'll give it a go.

Comment: Nice! I'm glad it was useful to you! :D